# How do I get full-height bootstrap nav buttons?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, nav

The default bootstrap nav does this when the screen is too small:

[image: Button too small problem]

The gap beneath the 'Hotels' button shouldn't be there when I hover over the link, it's caused by the 'Private Hire' text being too long and pushing the nav down a bit.

Is there any way to get the white background to take up the full height of the nav?

Comment: can u provide ur sample code here

Comment: It's actually built in .NET as part of a CMS so it wouldn't be much help, but it's built in the same way as http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have been looking into the twitter bootstrap navbar and i found a way to get rid of that whitespace.

Quite simple....

```
.navbar-nav{
    white-space: nowrap;
}

@media (min-width: 1200px){
    .navbar-nav {
        font-size: 22px;
    }
}
@media (min-width: 994px) and (max-width: 1199px){
    .navbar-nav {
        font-size: 17px;
    }
}
@media (max-width: 994px){
    .navbar-nav {
        font-size: 15px;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE 2:**

Now I've got it. Please check this `css` code:

```
<style> a {     color: #fff; }

.navbar {
    background-color: #122B41 !important;
    color: #fff;
                height:100px; }

.navbar > div { height:100% !important; }

.navbar > div > div { height:100% !important; }

.navbar > div > div > ul { height:100% !important; } 

.navbar > div > div > ul > li { height:100% !important; } 

.navbar > div > div > ul > li > a { height:100% !important; } 

.navbar-collapse.collapse {     height:100% !important; } </style>
```

As I wrote in my UPDATE 1 statement, it's based on the default example of the bootstrap navbar.
Does this solve your problem?

**UPDATE 1:**

I've created a blank page, just with the default `navbar` example from the `bootstrap` page. I've just added some color via `css` (see `style` area) for better color display of the `navbar`. Here is the code of my default page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8"></meta>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap.min.css"></link>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap-theme.min.css"></link>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap-theme.min.css.map"></link>
<style>
a {
    color: #fff;
}

.navbar {
    background-color: #122B41 !important;
    color: #fff;
}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.12.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="npm.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<nav class="navbar navbar-primary">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Link <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <form class="navbar-form navbar-left">
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
      </form>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm wondering, because the default navbar, has exactly the desired "full-height". Please see my screenshot:

[image]

Maybe you provide the code of your `navbar` and additional `css` of your page?

**ORIGINAL:**

You can set the `line-height` property of the link accordingly to the height of your navbar via `css`.

```
.navbar-nav>li>a {
    line-height: <height_of_your_navbar>px;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately that just bulks out the height of the button rather than spanning the full height of the nav (the height is subject to change when adding/removing buttons through the CMS). I was hoping to find something that just puts the height to 100% of the nav but I've had no luck yet!